# incremental counter and array.sort

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, counter, increment

Does anyone know why my "number" variable in the incremental counter at the (for(p=0; p< number; p=p+1) not identifying the integer (it's located at the totalscore function)? It's suppose to print out between 3 to 5 random number instead of 1 random number. Also, after the 3-5 random number is printed out, i plan to store those values into an array and sort them using an array sort. But the problem is that all 3-5 random value's are stored in one variable. Any helpful suggestions would be much appreciated. Sorry if my code is messy, I'm still a beginner in this and i hope my explanation is good enough for you to understand

```html
< HTML>
  < !Foundation Page for building our Javascript programs>
    < HEAD>
      < TITLE>The Foundation Page
        < /TITLE>
          <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
            var number;

            function main() {
              start()
              totalscore()
              leaderboard()
            }

            function start() {
              var ask
              var name1
              var name2
              var name3
              var name4
              var name5




              ask = prompt("How many people are playing")
              if (ask == 3) {
                name1 = prompt("What is the first player's name?")
                name2 = prompt("What is the second player's name?")
                name3 = prompt("What is the third player's name?")
                number = 3
              }
              if (ask == 4) {
                name1 = prompt("What is the first player's name?")
                name2 = prompt("What is the second player's name?")
                name3 = prompt("What is the third player's name?")
                name4 = prompt("What is the forth player's name?")
                number = 4
              }
              if (ask == 5) {
                name1 = prompt("What is the first player's name?")
                name2 = prompt("What is the second player's name?")
                name3 = prompt("What is the third player's name?")
                name4 = prompt("What is the forth player's name?")
                name5 = prompt("What is the fifth player's name?")
                number = 5
              }
            }

            function randomnumber() {
              var randomnumber;
              randomnumber = Math.random() * 3;
              return (Math.floor(randomnumber + 0.2));
            }

            function totalscore() {
              var n;
              var p;
              var score = 0;
              var total;

              for (p = 0; p < number; p = p + 1) {
                total = 0
                for (n = 0; n < 10; n = n + 1) {
                  number = randomnumber();
                  if (number == 0) {
                    score = score + 0;
                  } else if (number == 2) {
                    score = score + 2;
                  } else if (number == 3) {
                    score = score + 3;
                  }
                  total = total + score;
                }
                document.write("These's player will have the following score")
                document.write(total + "<br>")

              }

            }

            function leaderboard() {

              var leader = new array(5);

              leader[0] =
                leader[1] =
                leader[2] =
                leader[3] =
                leader[4] =




            }
          </SCRIPT>
          < HEAD>
            < BODY>
              < BODY BGCOLOUR="WHITE">
                < H2>The Foundation Page
                  < /H2>
                    <HR>
                    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="Javascript">
                      main()
                    </SCRIPT>
                    < /BODY>

                      </HTML>
```

Comment: That is some ugly formatting, please fix your HTML tags and indentation.

Comment: just a point but your html is incorrect - you have 2 opening head tags and 2 opening body tags.  Aside from this, if you check your console, does it show any errors?

Comment: What is 
`leader[0]= 
leader[1]= 
leader[2]= 
leader[3]= 
leader[4]= ` ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should adopt some code standard: currently you code looks very fancyful, so it doesn't help others to review it... and even it doesn't help you!

So you should consider the followning points:

1. for HTML tags, use only lowercase and don't insert spaces inside: write `<html>` rather than `< HTML >`
2. pay attention to conform you to HTML syntax rules:

   - don't write a comment like `< !Foundation Page for building our Javascript programs >`, but `<!-- Foundation Page for building our Javascript programs -->`
   - drop obsolete attributes like in `<SCRIPT LANGUAGE = "JavaScript">`: simply write `<script>`
   - properly close your `</head>` tag (currently written `< HEAD >`)
   - don't use obsolete presentation attributes like ìn `< BODY BGCOLOUR = "WHITE" >`: use CSS instead, writing something like `body {background-color: white;}` inside of a `<style>` element or .css file
   - repeating `<body>` tag has no sense
   - in javascript code, even if optional, prefer to always put a semicolon at the end of each statement
   - keep consistent with the standard notation you're using: either write something like `a=b+c;` everywhere, or everywhere `a = b + c;`, but don't mix those two kinds of expression

Now regarding your question: in addition to the items listed above there are also, even at a simple glance, a number of reasons why this code can't work, at leas the one you posted.
Then since you're reporting an issue like "`number` variable not recognized or not getting the expected value" it means you had your code working in a different state than what you posted (or you are using a particularly tolerant browser, I'd be curious to know :-).
**Please post code in a state corresponding to the issue your question concerns!**

In any case here are some points yet I suggest to review:

1. You may simplify your general code structure in 2 ways:

   - first don't separate javascript in 2 parts: you can merely have a unique `<script>`, located just before `/body>` and containing both your functions and your `main()`call
   - regarding the launch process, instead of calling `main()`, which itself calls the other functions, have directly those other calls as script body
2. I understand that your `leaderbord()` function is currently not achieved, but never keeped it featuring so meantime, or the entire application won't work; at least globally comment it
3. remember that when a variable is defined inside of a function it is known only there, and not outside: so for example all your `nameX`variables are useless when exited from the `start()` function
4. directly regarding your issue about the `number` variables:

   - first you define it as a global variable, where you save the user prompt result from `ask()`
   - then in `totalscore()`function you have this value used to loop on this number of users, **but also overwrite it by the value you get from `randomnumber()`function: obviously then it can't drive loop process any longer! Here you **must** use a different (local) variable for saving the random value
5. in the other hand, the `ask()` function can be dramatically shortened in several points (look at the proposed code below); also there is a lack about what the program should do when `number` is other than 3, 4, or 5, or even empty or not numeric
6. `randomnumber()` function is useless, since it used only once **and** doesn't consist of a some complex code

Here is a code suggestion enhanced according with the items pointed above, plus some other minor ones. But **note that it is still far from really good**, not only at the coding style point of view but also regarding strategy and effectiveness.

```
<html>
<!-- Foundation Page for building our Javascript programs -->
  <head>
    <title>The Foundation Page</title>
    <style>
body {
  background-color: white;
}
    </style>
    <script>
var number,
    names = start(); // so names can be used further
    totalscore();
    leaderboard();
function start() {
    var names = [];
    number = prompt ("How many people are playing");
  for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    names[i] = prompt("What is the player " + i + "'s name?");
  }
  return names;
}
function totalscore() {
    var total,
      score = 0;
  for(var p = 0; p < number; p++) {
    total = 0;
    for (var n = 0; n < 10; n++) {
      var randomvalue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 0.2);
      if (randomvalue == 0) {
        score = score + 0;
      }
      else if (randomvalue == 2) {
        score = score + 2;
      }
      else if (randomvalue == 3) {
        score = score + 3;
      }
    total = total + score;
    }
  document.write ("These's player will have the following score: ");
  document.write( total + "<br />");
  }
}
function leaderboard () {
/*
  var leader = new array(5);
  leader[0]= 
  leader[1]= 
  leader[2]= 
  leader[3]= 
  leader[4]= 
*/
}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2> The Foundation Page </h2>
    <hr />
  </body>
</html>
```